# Is there a way to mock the built-in require function in Perl?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocking

I am developing an application that has to replace an existing mess of spaghetti-code piece by piece. To achieve this I have a dispatcher that runs required HTTP resources when a URI has been matched and otherwise uses the legacy HTTP resource class.

So, this legacy HTTP resource has to `require` the entry point file of the old system, and I'm trying to figure out how to test this process. The way I see it now is I would like to replace the original `require` function with a mock subroutine and check that it has been called with an appropriate file name.

Is this possible, and if not, maybe there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A better way to override `require` globally may be to install a hook into `@INC`.  This little-known functionality is described at the end of [the `require` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html).

Here's a simple example that intercepts any request for a module whose name begins with HTTP:

```
BEGIN {
  unshift @INC, sub {
    my ($self, $file) = @_;
    return unless $file =~ /^HTTP/;
    print "Creating mock $file\n";
    my @code = "1"; # Fake module must return true
    return sub { $_ = shift @code; defined $_ };
  }
}

require HTTP::Foo;
use HTTPBar;
```

Note that this also mocks `use`, since it's based on `require`.

Answer (score 14):

To override `require` in a single package:

```
use subs 'require';  # imports `require` so it can be overridden

sub require {print "mock require: @_\n"}
```

To override `require` globally:

```
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::require = sub {print "mock require: @_\n"}
}
```

And then:

```
require xyz;           # mock require: xyz.pm

require Some::Module;  # mock require: Some/Module.pm
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mock the `require` function only for that module? I need it to be mocked for all other modules as well.

Answer (score 3):

Hooks can be added as code refs into your `@INC` path. These will then be applied globally to both `use` and `require` statements.

To quote perldoc [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html)

> You can also insert hooks into the import facility by putting Perl code directly into the @INC array.
>
> There are three forms of hooks: subroutine references, array references, and blessed objects.
>
> Subroutine references are the simplest case. When the inclusion system walks through @INC and encounters a subroutine, this subroutine gets called with two parameters, the first a reference to itself, and the second the name of the file to be included (e.g., "Foo/Bar.pm"). The subroutine should return either nothing or else a list of up to three values in the following order:
>
> 1. A filehandle, from which the file will be read.
>
> 2. A reference to a subroutine. If there is no filehandle (previous item), then this subroutine is expected to generate one line of source code per call, writing the line into $_ and returning 1, then finally at end of file returning 0. If there is a filehandle, then the subroutine will be called to act as a simple source filter, with the line as read in $_ . Again, return 1 for each valid line, and 0 after all lines have been returned.
>
> 3.Optional state for the subroutine. The state is passed in as $_[1] . A reference to the subroutine itself is passed in as $_[0]

Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub my_inc_hook {
    my ($sub_ref, $file) = @_;

    unless ($file =~ m{^HTTP/}) {
        warn "passing through: $file\n";
        return;
    }

    warn "grokking: $file\n";
    return (\*DATA);
}

BEGIN {
    unshift(@INC, \&my_inc_hook);
}

use strict;
require warnings;
require HTTP::Bazinga;

HTTP::Bazinga::it_works();

__DATA__
package HTTP::Bazinga;

sub it_works {warn "bazinga!\n"};

1;
```

Produces:

```
$ perl inc.pl
passing through: strict.pm
passing through: warnings.pm
grokking: HTTP/Bazinga.pm
bazinga!
```

I believe this works for perl 5.10.0 and above.

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation, I have accepted a similar answer, which, I believe was posted first.